# what the difference between function(x: Tarray<String>) and function(x: array of string)

Tags: delphi

What the difference between `function(x: Tarray<String>)` and `function(x: array of string)`, especially what are the drawback and advantage to each variants ?

Comment: Generics = more memory usage (exe space) and slower in general. Both are flexible in your example but I'd suggest the open array way

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi Wrong, `TArray<T>` is a simple type def. Stop spreading wrong fud please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First is a dynamic array parameter, second is an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Open_Arrays) parameter.

Open array parameters usually give you the benefit to just pass the values in square brackets like so:

```
foobar([x, y, z]);
```

Since XE7 you can also initialize dynamic array that way with a little more overhead. In the end it depends on what you are doing with the values. If you are not storing them an open array parameter often is enough. However if you want to store the values in an array you cannot just assign that to any dynamic array parameter but have to copy the values.

While the syntax for a dynamic array and an open array parameter is the same (`array of X`) they are not assignment compatible in both directions (you can only pass a dynamic array to an open array parameter but cannot assign an open array parameter to a dynamic array variable.

One thing you should consider if you are using open array parameters on methods that you want to invoke via RTTI - that does not work because RTTI is not handling them properly - see [RSP-16317](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16317).

Additionally `TArray<X>` should be preferred over some explicit declared array type like `TXArray = array of X` because `TAnotherXArray = array of X` would not be compatible to the `TXArray` but `TArray<T>` or an alias `TXArray = TArray<T>` is always type compatible.

For more info refer to Rudy's excellent [article about open array parameters](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).

Comment: Heheh, I was just typing a comment referring to my article when I saw your last line. Thanks for the praise.